# How to create HTML Log File from Jmeter

Tags: logging, log4j, jmeter

I need to create HTML Log file from jmeter.So I put log4j.jar into the bin folder where log4j.conf file present and add this to the log4j.conf file

```
# Define the HTML file appender
log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
# Path and file name to store the log file
log4j.appender.HTML.File=./logs/application.html
# Define the html layout for file appender
log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
#Define Title of the HTML page
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=Application logs
#Define the log location of application class file
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true
```

but no application.html file was generated.I also try this to put log4j.jar file into the lib,ext and bin folder but I didnot get any html log file after running the jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put log4j.jar in lib folder not bin.

Second this log4j configuration will only be used by libraries that use log4j for their logging.

JMeter does not use log4j, it uses logkit, and configuration is to be done in user.properties, look for Logging configuration block.

**As a consequence you cannot OOTB generate HTML from logs for JMeter packages**

As a proof of what I say about this, see:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.jmeter.user/6253
- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-jmeter-dev/200502.mbox/%3C25aac9fc0502230646d7271ad@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help.I do the same thing as you mentioned except I can not modify the jmeter.properties file because I can not understand the logging configuration.I cannot understand how to implement the log4j configuration with it.Please help me to configure the log4j within the jmeter.properties file by which I can get HTML log file.